# Rendering a view file in self made PHP MVC framework

Tags: php

I've developed My Own MVC Framework using php.
I call view files in controller like:

```
include('../view/home.php');
```

but I want to use it like:

```
$this->view('home');
```

How can I define common function for that where I can just pass view name i.e `home` only and it will do include view file without passing the full file path?

Comment: Why not have a variable `$this->viewPath` and then in the function just concatenate the viewPath with the value passed to the view function? See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50162193/3578036

Comment: That's not a view. It's a template. Views are classes, that contain the presentation logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No one could answer you without seeing your codes really. But this should be my approach.
You should have a class that all your controllers extend. Lets say that you have class Controllers and all your controllers extend it.

Then you may have a method inside the class named view($view_name).

```
public function view($view_name){
   include $some_path . '/' . $view_name . '.php';
}
```

then whenever you call view by $this->view it will include the view if it exists.
This is not the best approach and I did not test the code. I just wanted to show you the path

Answer (score 2):

I don't know Your MVC file/directory/namespace and etc structure.

But for beginner who tries to learn MVC and Frameworks by "reinventing wheel" (: I can give such example:

1) Create common abstract controller class in `app/controllers` folder:

```
namespace App\Controllers;

abstract class Controller {

  public function view($name) {
    include(__DIR__.'/../views/'.$name.'.php';
  }

}
```

2) Create Your own controller i.e. `PagesController` and use it:

```
namespace App\Controllers;

class PagesController extends Controller {

  public function home() {
    $this->view('home');
  }
}
```

p.s. You may omit **namespace**-ing, **abstract** word  depending on autoloader logic